# Install iOS IPA via Xcode with no certificate in keychain and no provisioning profile installed

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning

I have an oracle VM with OSX ML installed on it. I want to install an IPA via Xcode organiser, its properly provisioned for my iPhone UDID. Is it possible to install it on my iphone, when there is no certificate in my keychain access as wel as there is no provisioning profile installed on my system.

I have just an IPA, properly code-signed for my iPhone. As its first time for my iPhone, so I also have iTunes Connect account to start development login via organiser.

Will it be possible to install it like that or we need to install certificates and provisioning profiles first to install an IPAw  to my iphone?

Comment: Please come up with an answer as i badly need that. Its a rare thing that one might face during iOS development. There is nothing off topic in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have IPA file signed for correct iPhone device, all you require is iPhone data cable and iTunes installed on either MAC/PC.

Certificate and provisioning profile is required only for creating IPA file by building source code.

Hope that helps!

Comment: On windows/mac connect iPhone: double click .IPA, it will be opened in iTunes, Click connected iphone> apps> install. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to run the application on your Device using the XCode you need to have certificate in keychain access as wel as provisioning profile installed on your system.
2. What you can do is you can install it using the iTunes.
3. As you have the .ipa file build with provisioning profile which had your UDID, it'll be installed using the iTunes.

Comment: We can install .IPA using xcode by clicking on Organizer>Connected DeviceName on left panel> Applications> "+" sign at bottom. I have done it many times and its totally possible.

Comment: @NaXir You sir, have just saved me hours worth of trouble. Thanks man.

Comment: @Rushi does it work if event though i am not associated to the developper account where the certificate is from?

Comment: Yes you can still install it.